# Failing to install ruby-runtime due to null pointer exception

Tags: ruby, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to install the ruby-runtime (0.12) plugin for Jenkins, but getting the following error:

```
ruby-runtime    
 Failure -
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.jenkinsci.jruby.JavaProxyConverter.canConvert(JavaProxyConverter.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.DefaultConverterLookup.registerConverter(DefaultConverterLookup.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$2.registerConverter(XStream.java:502)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.registerConverter(XStream.java:1422)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.registerConverter(XStream.java:1417)
    at org.jenkinsci.jruby.JRubyXStream.register(JRubyXStream.java:26)
    at ruby.RubyRuntimePlugin.initRubyXStreams(RubyRuntimePlugin.java:44)
    at ruby.RubyRuntimePlugin.start(RubyRuntimePlugin.java:28)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.startPlugin(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:539)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:528)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to initialize
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:531)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:872)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install ruby-runtime plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:881)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:820)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1889)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1893)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've found some questions on similar issues, however none of them seem to address this specific issue. Would greatly appreciate any assistance or where to go towards in terms of troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?